# $ord_p(x)$ -Units and Irreducibles

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> > Let $p$ be a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $R = R_p = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}\ |\ ord_p(x)\geq0\}$, which is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$.
> >
> > (a) Show that $x \in R$ is a unit iff $ord_p(x)=0$
> >
> > (b) Show that $x \in R$ is irreducible iff $ord_p(x)=1$ and that $p$ is the only irreducible in $R$ up to associates.
> >
> > (c) Show that the only nonzero ideals of $R$ are the principal ideals $(p^e)$ for $e\geq0$, so that $R$ is a PID.
> >
> > (d) Show that every nonzero $x \in R$ can be uniquely expressed as $x=up^e$ with $u$ a unit of $R$ and $e\geq0$. Deduce that $R$ is a unique factorization domain with only one irreducible (up to associates), namely $p$.
> >
> > (e) Can you generalise this to construct UFDs with exactly two irreducibles (up to associates)? Exactly $n$?

(a) Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and write $x= \frac{p^ea}{b}$ where $a,b$ are integers not divisible by $p$. So $ord_p(x)=e$. Now if $ord_p(x)=0$, $x=\frac{a}{b} \in R_P$ and so $\frac{b}{a} \in R_p$ is its inverse. But if $e>0$, $x^{-1} \notin R_p$ since $ord_p(x)<0$.

(b) Irreducible if it is neither $0$ nor a unit and $p=ab$ implies $a$ or $b$ is a unit.

If $x$ is irreducible then $ord_p(x)\neq0$ since otherwise it would be a unit.

Now I am stuck and need some hints.

Comment: Do you know anything about localizations?

Answer (score 1):

To prove (b), since it's an iff we can do each direction seperately.

First, if $ord_p(x) = 1$ then $x$ is irreducible: suppose for contradiction that $x = ab$ then $1 = ord_p(x) = ord_p(a) + ord_p(b)$ implies that one of $ord_p(a),ord_p(b)$ is $0$ and the other is $1$ since the valuation is discrete.

Secondly, if $x$ is irreducible then $ord_p(x) = 1$: We know that $ord_p(x) > 0$, so suppose for contradiction that $ord_p(x) > 1$. If that were so then $x$ is a multiple of $p$ so there exists some $y$ with $x = py$ and $ord_p(p) = 1$, $ord_p(y) > 0$.

Comment: Is my (a) correct ? Wasn't sure about my reasoning towards the end

Comment: yeah it looks fine

Comment: Hello, I also need help with this question. How would I approach parts c and d?

Comment: @George, the best thing to do would be ask that as a new question I think.

Comment: Where is the contradiction in the second part of your answer?